# NameError: name 'productId' is not defined in pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Could figure how to fix this issue. I need to save data to database via Pymysql This script gave me error :

"cursor.execute(sql_template, {"productId": productId, "productTitle": productTitle, "salePrice": salePrice,
NameError: name 'productId' is not defined"

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='Kradz579032!!',
                                 db='aliexpressapidb',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql_template ="""
            INSERT INTO producttable (productId, productTitle, salePrice, originalPrice )
                SELECT * FROM (SELECT %(productId)s, %(productTitle)s, %(salePrice)s, %(originalPrice)s) AS tmp
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT productId FROM producttable WHERE productId = %(productId)s
                )
                LIMIT 1;
            """

            for product in data['products']:
                print('%s %s %s %s' % (
                product['productId'], product['productTitle'], product['salePrice'], product['originalPrice']))

                cursor.execute(sql_template, {"productId": productId, "productTitle": productTitle, "salePrice": salePrice,
                                              "originalPrice": originalPrice})
            connection.commit()

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: how do you create this "cursor.executemany(sql_template, data["products"])" ?

Comment: @absolutely no clue what you were saying because I'm a beginner in Python. Could you show me how to fix this (https://hastebin.com/orafalanok.py) instead ?